# How to list all files in mlocate database file?

Tags: files, locate

when `updatedb` is run it generates a `mlocate.db` file. 
How to list all the files in the mlocate.db file?

```
locate *
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct command will be `locate '*'` or `locate "*"` or `locate \*`.

The `*` has to be quoted to avoid having the shell expand it to names present in the current working directory.

Comment: Works on my Ubuntu but my hopeless Mac shows nothing (built in and Macports installation shows nothing)